# Why does one of these SQL queries work but the other doesn't?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is being done in PostgreSQL 12. I fail to understand why the following query works (as in it returns two rows):

```sql
SELECT facid, name, membercost, monthlymaintenance
FROM cd.facilities
WHERE membercost > 0 AND membercost < (monthlymaintenance * 1/50);
```

but this one doesn't (it returns nothing):

```sql
SELECT facid, name, membercost, monthlymaintenance
FROM cd.facilities
WHERE membercost > 0 AND membercost < (1/50) * monthlymaintenance;
```

But if I replace `1/50` in the second query with `0.02`, it works. Why is this happening? What am I missing here? I haven't been able to find an answer to this in the postgres mathematical operations documentation either. Please do point me to the correct part if it's there.

Also, feel free to edit the question title to make it more discoverable because I couldn't think of a more "general" title given the specific nature of it.

Comment: In one query you are dividing integers, which results in an integer (0) and throws away the remainder (1).  That is how integer division works.  In the other you multiplying an (apparent) floating point type by an integer, which results in a float, then dividing by an integer, which again results in a float.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html, search for 'integer division'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres functions and operators are typed. `1/50` uses integer division and will only return the integer part.

```
# select 1/50;
 ?column? 
----------
        0
```

To do floating point division, one of the numbers must be a floating point

```
# select 1::float/50;
 ?column? 
----------
     0.02
```

or numeric

```
# select 1::numeric/50;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.02000000000000000000
```

`(1/50) * monthlymaintenance` does not work because it is `0 * monthlymaintenance`.

`monthlymaintenance * 1/50` works because `monthlymaintenance` is presumably a float or numeric column. Operator precedence says...

- `float * integer / integer` is equivalent to
- `(float * integer) / integer` becomes
- `float / integer` becomes
- `float`

`1/50 * monthlymaintenance` would also not work because `1/50` is resolved first to `0 * monthlymaintenance`.